# How does require work?

Tags: node.js

I have 2 files in a folder called js. I am using webpack.

js/app.js  and js/login.es6.

I'm trying to include the login from my app.js:

```
require('login.es6') fails
require('./login.es6') works.
```

Any idea why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write `require('login.es6')` node will look for a module named `login.es6` in your node_modules.

When you write `require('./login.es6')` node understands that `./login.es6` is a relative path and will load your `js/login.es6.js` file.

Answer (score 0):

This is needed to distinguish between modules and local files. There may be a npm module called `login.es6`; this way you can reference both the module and your local file in your project.

Answer (score 0):

The node.js docs on `require` are pretty nice and gives a [good overview](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v6.x/docs/api/modules.html#modules_all_together) of how modules are prioritized when loaded.

The gist is, if you don't start the string with `./`, `require` will first look for a core module, then recursively look in the `node_modules` directory/-ies. So it's normal to start require calls to local files with `./`.